# Python use ternary operator with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, conditional-operator

I am trying to transform this

```
def opt_config(opts):
    for x, x2 in opts:
        if x == "--config":
            return x2
    return str()
```

With a ternary operator like

```
return x2 if x == "--config" for x, x2 in opts else str()
```

But it seems not to work. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a generator expression for that:

```py
return next((x2 for x, x2 in opts if x == "--config"), str())
```

The expression `(x2 for x, x2 in opts if x == 1)` is a generator: it
can be used to iterate over a set of elements.  For instance:

```py
opts = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
gen = (x2 for x, x2 in opts if x == 1)
for x in gen:
  print(x)  #  print 2 and 3
```

`next` returns the next element of the generator (or the first if you
have not generated any element for now).

If the generator does not contain any next element, then the second
(optional) argument of `next` is returned.  Otherwise an exception is raised.  For instance:

```py
opts = [(1, 2), (2, 3)]

gen = (x2 for x, x2 in opts if x == 4)
x = next(gen)  #  raise StopIteration

gen = (x2 for x, x2 in opts if x == 4)
x = next(gen, 5)
print(x)  # print 5
```

So to summarise, `return next((x2 for x, x2 in opts if x == "--config"), str())` is equivalent to your for loop: using your generator you take the first element `x, x2` of `opts` such that `x == "--config"` and return `x2` ; and if there is no such element you return `str()`

Comment: Added some explanations. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. Do you think this is pythonic solution?

Comment: In my view pythonic means simple and readable.  So the plain for loop solution is perhaps better than the generator as you can directly understand its logic whereas the generator requires more mental work.

Comment: I agree with your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few pieces to this.

The fallback return of `str()` will always give `''` as you are asking it for the string value of literally nothing. If that's what you want you might as well return `''` instead.

Unless all of your opts are 2-tuples (or other iterables with 2 elements each), then anything singleton opt will fail at `for x, x2 in opts`. At a guess, you are more likely feeding a list of strings to this function, examples being

```
opt_config(['--config', 'elderberries', 'castle']) -> 'elderberries'
opt_config(['grail', 'swallow', '--config', 'rabbit']) -> 'rabbit'
opt_config(['parrot', 'cheese', 'Olympics']) -> ''
```

Again, speculating on what you want, it appears you want either the first config option given (and only the first), or `''` if `'--config'` never shows up.

If my interpretations of your intentions are correct, then something like this might be what you want for the 'non-ternary' version of the code:

```
def opt_config(opts):
    if '--config' in opts:
        ndx = opts.index('--config')
        if ndx < len(opts):
            return opts[ndx + 1]
    return ''

opt_config(['--config', 'elderberries', 'castle'])
'elderberries'

opt_config(['grail', 'swallow', '--config', 'rabbit'])
'rabbit'

opt_config(['parrot', 'cheese', 'Olympics'])
''
```

If you want to compress that code down you can take it all the way to a 1-liner using the ternary operator you asked about:

```
opt_config2 = lambda opts: opts[opts.index('--config') + 1] if '--config' in opts[:-1] else ''

opt_config2(['--config', 'elderberries', 'castle'])
'elderberries'

opt_config2(['grail', 'swallow', '--config', 'rabbit'])
'rabbit'

opt_config2(['parrot', 'cheese', 'Olympics'])
''
```

With the ternary operator `x if y else z`, the `if y` part is evaluated first, so python efficiently calculates only one of the `x` and `z` options as required.

Comment: I will considerate this refactoring, thanks